# Display multiple datamember in gridview

Tags: c#

can i display multiple datamember in datagridview
if i have class like this

```
class Person{
string firstname;
string lastname;
}
```

and this class

```
class PersonDifference{
Person Person1;
Person Person2;
}
```

and i want display just firstname from person1 and person2

i use data member like this

```
datagridview1.DataSource=ListOfPersonDifference;
datagridview1.DataMember="Person1.firstname,Person2.firstname";
```

but it didn't work can you help me please

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" can you elaborate?

Comment: datagridview.datamember not identified Person1.firstname,Person2.firstname but if I use this datagridview1.DataMember="Person1" it works but that's not what i need